# Javascript decrement -- not working in my script

Tags: javascript

```
var backgroundImages = new Array(); // create an array holding the links of each image
        backgroundImages[0] = "style/images/bg0.png"; 
        backgroundImages[1] = "style/images/bg1.png";
        backgroundImages[2] = "style/images/bg2.png";
        backgroundImages[3] = "style/images/bg3.png";
        backgroundImages[4] = "style/images/bg4.png";
        backgroundImages[5] = "style/images/bg5.png";
        backgroundImages[6] = "style/images/bg6.png";

        var ImageCnt = 0;

        function nextImage(direction) // this should take into account the current value (starts at 3) and determines whether a higher or lower value should be returned based on the direction
        {
            if(direction == "left")
            {
            ImageCnt-- ;
            }
            if(direction == "right")
            {
            ImageCnt++ ;
            }
            document.getElementById("body-1").style.background = 'url(' + backgroundImages[ImageCnt] + ')'; //put's the new background together for rendering by using the returned value from nextImage()
            if(ImageCnt == 6)
            {
                ImageCnt = -1;
            }
        }
```

In this script, ImageCnt ++ is working fine, on the function "nextImage('right')" but on nextImage('left') which triggers ImageCnt-- , the function breaks. What am I doing wrong? (Newbie with js)

Comment: Your question says this: `netImage('left')`. Is that a typo here, or copied from your script?

Comment: Just checking: "but on `netImage('left')`" is a typo, right? You are testing with `nextImage('left')`?

Comment: Could the problem be that you're running off the left end of the array?

Comment: @user2357112 Most likely. That is essentially what Kolink is suggesting below.

Comment: Right, Kolink is correct below, that was a badly thought out script ^_^ - Thank you guys for checking out this problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, your "wrap" code says to make it -1, but what if I then go left? It will try to access -2, which doesn't exist.

Try this instead:

```
ImageCnt = (ImageCnt + (direction == "left" ? backgroundImages.length-1 : 1)) % backgroundImages.length;
document.getElementById("body-1").style.background = "url('"+backgroundImages[ImageCnt]+"')";
```

Note also that it is very inefficient to build an array piece by piece like that. Try this:

```
var backgroundImages = [
  "style/images/bg0.png",
  "style/images/bg1.png",
  "style/images/bg2.png",
  "style/images/bg3.png",
  "style/images/bg4.png",
  "style/images/bg5.png",
  "style/images/bg6.png",
];
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this now

Comment: Ok, this fixed it, thank you very much. I am new and working on learning these concepts, and while your code works, I'm working to understand how it works so I can improve my code in the future, would you mind quickly explaining that scripting for ImageCnt?

Comment: Basically, the important part is `%`. It ensures that the value we have is in the valid range of the array's size. The `direction == "left"` bit is a shortcut. If we're going left, it adds "length of the array minus 1" (avoids some nasty gotchas with `%` and negative numbers), and if we're going right it just adds one.